$h:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ strictly increase. $\frac{h(x)}x$ strictly decrease. Prove $h(x+y)\leq h(x)+h(y)$.
Note that we do not know the differentiability of $h$, so we cannot take the derivative of $h$.
Here are some of my attempts.
Without loss of generality, let $x\leq y$, then
$$h(x+y)=(x+y)\frac{h(x+y)}{x+y}\leq(x+y)\frac{h(y)}y=\frac xyh(y)+h(y)\leq2h(y),\quad {\rm fail.}$$
$$h(x+y)=(x+y)\frac{h(x+y)}{x+y}\leq(x+y)\frac{h(x)}x=h(x)+\frac yxh(x)\leq h(x)+\frac yxh(y),\quad {\rm fail.}$$
$$h(x+y)=(x+y)\frac{h(x+y)}{x+y}\leq(x+y)\left(\frac{h(x)}{2x}+\frac{h(y)}{2y}\right)\leq\frac{x+y}{2x}h(x)+h(y),\quad {\rm fail.}$$
I don't think my scaling is excessive, but no matter how I scale, if I want to get the final result, there is always an inequality that is inverse. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Hint:  You came close in the first line. You've not used $h(x) / x  \geq h(y) / y $ as yet.

You came close in the first line.  Continuing from your work,
$ \quad h(x+y)\\
=(x+y)\frac{h(x+y)}{x+y} \\
\leq(x+y)\frac{h(y)}y \\
= x  \frac{h(y)}{y} +h(y) \\ $

 $ \leq x \frac{ h(x) } { x} + h(y) $
$= h(x) + h(y) $.

Note:

We didn't use that $h(x)$ strictly increases.
In a way, this combines the "good parts" from your first 2 lines.


Ah, I didn't get such a simple idea at the first time. It's too embarrassing. Thank you very much :)
